# Several hundreds calls of ActiveRecord#create and ActiveRecord#destory causes ActionController::Session::CookieStore::CookieOverflow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I call ActiveRecord#create and ActiveRecord#destroy method several hundreds times(more than 200), **Status: 500 Internal Server Error, ActionController::Session::CookieStore::CookieOverflow** occured.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This errors say you have a cookie more than 4Ko. It's not a ActiveRecord issue.

You need puts less thing in your session or change your session store.

Comment: I've just called ActiveRecord#destroy. Is this method use session? I didn't use any session related things I think.(I use Authlogic and that's all)
Anyway, are there any method to empty session?

Comment: This method don't call session. Maybe some code help us to help you

Comment: I found the problem! I've put too much data into [flash] :(